# Convert 6 array-bytes to int64 using PHP

Tags: php

I'm reverse engineering a javascript script to PHP and there are many functions that convert:

6 array bytes of [224, 221, 199, 147, 195, 47]

and output that to 1632933900000 (which is timestamp, Int64)

Can you help me how to pack/unpack those bytes as above to the final integer using PHP ?

### Samples:

[224, 221, 199, 147, 195, 47] gets to 1632933900000

[224, 143, 228, 137, 198, 47]
gets to 1633718700000

#### ADDITIONAL INFO:

The javascript code is very long (it was obfuscated). I just know for certain that it is placed within 6 bytes.

[image]

### NEXT UPDATE...

It goes to this function (this.buf is array-bytes):

```
function u() {
    var e = new a(0, 0),
        t = 0;
    if (!(this.len - this.pos > 4)) {
        for (; t < 3; ++t) {
            if (this.pos >= this.len) throw s(this);
            if (e.lo = (e.lo | (127 & this.buf[this.pos]) << 7 * t) >>> 0, this.buf[this.pos++] < 128) return e
        }
        return e.lo = (e.lo | (127 & this.buf[this.pos++]) << 7 * t) >>> 0, e
    }
    for (; t < 4; ++t)
        if (e.lo = (e.lo | (127 & this.buf[this.pos]) << 7 * t) >>> 0, this.buf[this.pos++] < 128) return e;
    if (e.lo = (e.lo | (127 & this.buf[this.pos]) << 28) >>> 0, e.hi = (e.hi | (127 & this.buf[this.pos]) >> 4) >>> 0, this.buf[this.pos++] < 128) return e;
    if (t = 0, this.len - this.pos > 4) {
        for (; t < 5; ++t)
            if (e.hi = (e.hi | (127 & this.buf[this.pos]) << 7 * t + 3) >>> 0, this.buf[this.pos++] < 128) return e
    } else
        for (; t < 5; ++t) {
            if (this.pos >= this.len) throw s(this);
            if (e.hi = (e.hi | (127 & this.buf[this.pos]) << 7 * t + 3) >>> 0, this.buf[this.pos++] < 128) return e
        }
    throw Error("invalid varint encoding")
}
```

And then it has [hi and low] numbers and this gets the timestamp:

```
 o.prototype.toNumber = function(e) {
    if (!e && this.hi >>> 31) {
        var t = 1 + ~this.lo >>> 0,
            n = ~this.hi >>> 0;
        return t || (n = n + 1 >>> 0), -(t + 4294967296 * n)
    }
    return this.lo + 4294967296 * this.hi
}
```

Comment: I see no way to map that integer to those bytes. It you convert 1632933900000 to bytes using the most common encoding scheme you get [1, 124, 50, 113, 238, 224] in big-endian, [224, 238, 113, 50, 124, 1] in little endian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to complete this answer I used following stuff, but I have absolutely no clue what it does :D

```
<?php
function int64_helper($obj)
{
    $e = (object) ['lo' => 0, 'hi' => 0];
    
    
    if (!($obj->len - $obj->pos > 4)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            if ($obj->pos >= $obj->len) throw new Exception('ERROR RANGE');
            $e->lo = rrr($e->lo | ((127 & $obj->buf[$obj->pos]) << (7 * $i)), 0);
            if ($obj->buf[$obj->pos++] < 128) return $e;
        }
        $e->lo = rrr($e->lo | ((127 & $obj->buf[$obj->pos++]) << (7 * $i)), 0);
        return $e;
    }
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        
        $e->lo = rrr($e->lo | ((127 & $obj->buf[$obj->pos]) << (7 * $i)), 0);
        
        if ($obj->buf[$obj->pos++] < 128) return $e;
    }
    
    $e->lo = rrr(($e->lo | ((127 & $obj->buf[$obj->pos]) << 28)), 0);
    $e->hi = rrr(($e->hi | rr((127 & $obj->buf[$obj->pos]), 4)), 0);
    if ($obj->buf[$obj->pos++] < 128) {
        return $e;
    }
    
    if ($obj->len - $obj->pos > 4) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            $e->hi = rrr($e->hi | ((127 & $obj->buf[$obj->pos]) << (7 * $i) + 3), 0);
            
            if ($obj->buf[$obj->pos++] < 128) return $e;
        }
    }
    else {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
            if ($obj->pos >= $obj->len) throw new Exception('ERROR RANGE');
            $e->hi = rrr($e->hi | ((127 & $obj->buf[$obj->pos]) << (7 * $i) + 3), 0);
            
            if ($obj->buf[$obj->pos++] < 128) return $e;
        }
    }
    
    throw new Exception("invalid timestamp encoding");
}


/**
* Date time
*/
function int64($obj)
{
    $e = int64_helper($obj);
    
    $mst = $e->lo + 4294967296 * $e->hi;
    
    $t = substr($mst, 0, -3); // poslední 3 nuly dávám pryč
    
    $s = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t); // prague timezone
    
    return $s;
}


/**
 * The >>> javascript operator in php x86_64
 * Usage: -1149025787 >>> 0 ---> rrr(-1149025787, 0) === 3145941509
 * @return int
 */
function rrr($v, $n)
{
    return ($v & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> ($n & 0x1F);
}

/**
 * The >> javascript operator in php x86_64
 * @return int
 */
function rr($v, $n)
{
    return ($v & 0x80000000 ? $v | 0xFFFFFFFF00000000 : $v & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> ($n & 0x1F);
}


/**
 * The << javascript operator in php x86_64
 * @return int
 */
function ll($v, $n)
{
    return ($t = ($v & 0xFFFFFFFF) << ($n & 0x1F)) & 0x80000000 ? $t | 0xFFFFFFFF00000000 : $t & 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: This hi/lo (with three hexadecimal digits each) has to do with [bit numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering). Different variable names might also make it more readable.... while I still think that a library alike [GMP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php), could do the same, while eventually even speed up low-level operations.

Answer (score 3):

`224 221 199 147 195 47` is the decimal representation of `E0 DD C7 93 C3 2F` ... which is `247243140743983` in decimal. Maybe not the whole dword is the timestamp ...for comparision: `01 7C 32 71 EE E0` or `61 54 98 0C`. One can already notice by the first digit, how far off this approach is.

---

That number in JS might be of type `BigInt`:

```
BigInt("0x017C3271EEE0")
```

But `BigInt("0xE0DDC793C32F")` still gives `247243140743983`.

Comment: Wait... so how did you get this [224, 221, 199, 147, 195, 47] to 017C3271EEE0 ... or that's just example from the result output?

Comment: Converting decimal to hexadecimal notation... with the stock Microsoft calculator, when switching to "programmer" mode .

Comment: Thank you for your time, it will be something with LongBits, maybe even custom encoded time... I'll figure it out.

Comment: Since the value is not being represented in a raw format... the most easy might be to just copy the JS code into a PHP IDE... and replicate all the [bit-shifting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). It seems to be [ZigZag](https://gist.github.com/mfuerstenau/ba870a29e16536fdbaba) encoding (or similar), which eg. protocol buffers use.